# combinatorics in a grid

Tags: algorithm, math, combinatorics

> We have a grid of 3 rows on 13 columns.
> On the first row, we have integers from 1 to 13 in ascending order.
> On the second row, we have these same integers in any order.
> On the third row, we write the absolute value of the difference of the two integers of each column.
> Let N be the number of ways to fill the 2nd row so that 13 distinct integers are on the 3rd row.
> Let N (k) be the number of solutions for which the integer k of the 1st and 2nd row appear in the same column.
> Thus, N is equal to the sum of N (k) for k ranging from 1 to 13.
>
> What is the sum of k x N (k) for k ranging from 1 to 13?

For instance, here's a solution with k=8 :

```
Row 1   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13
Row 2   5 13 12 11 10  7  9  8  6  4  3  2  1 
Row 3   4 11  9  7  5  1  2  0  3  6  8 10 12
```

Note how 8 is in the same position in rows 1 and 2, giving a 0 in row 3.  The quantity of such solutions is `N(8)`, and I would add `8 * N(8)` as that term in the requested summation.

Comment: What have you tried ? Where are you stuck ? Here's not the place where people do your homework / programming competition for you.

Comment: I'm stuck at the beginning of this problem. It's not a homework. Can you evaluate the level of the problem. It's a challenge from a (bad) friend.

Comment: The first step is to understand the question, and in particular the requirements. The requirement "Let N (k) be the number of solutions for which the integer k of the 1st and 2nd lines appear in the same column" does not seem to make any sense. If it means anything near what I think it may mean, the statement " N is equal to the sum of N (k) for k ranging from 1 to 13" is not true. Also, the use of "line" rather than "row" is confusing. Please clarify the requirements.

Comment: I don't have more accurate requirements

Comment: If you do not have any better requirements, and the question is from a friend, you should either refuse to do the problem on the basis of confusing and contradictory requirements or ask for clarification. If the question were a homework assignment I would ask the teacher for clarification. In either case I would delete this question and ask again later after clarification. Another confusing aspect is the that the actual question, the sum of `k x N(k)`, apparently has nothing to do with the third row.

Comment: As far as I understand the problem, the sum of k x N(k) is not directly connected with the third row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at a single solution for the first stage of the problem.  We'll let `k=8` for this example:

```
Row 1   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13
Row 2   5 13 12 11 10  7  9  8  6  4  3  2  1 
Row 3   4 11  9  7  5  1  2  0  3  6  8 10 12
```

Since each solution *must* have row 3 containing the integers 0-12, there will *always* be exactly one element in the same column in row 1 and 2.

Now, assume that there are 2 solutions with `8` being that element; you'd include `8 * 2` in your sum.

I would attack the problem via brute force (recursive placement function with backtracking).  Find all of the solutions, and then simply sum the "stable" element in each solution.  That's your final answer.